# Script for GIMP to make a certain area transparent for several images

Tags: gimp, automation, script

I would like to have a script to process a set of image files in png format, lets's say inside of one directory. We can also assume the images have the same size. The processing should contain of the following actions: select certain region, make it transparent, repeat for the next file.

Just an example to illustrate what I mean:

[image]

should be turned into

[image]

And

[image]

into

[image]

**edit**: @Paolo Gibbelini and @Scribblemacher, you made good suggestions. However I need now to slightly change my requirements. The width of the input image may be different and with of the crop area should be equal to the image width. The height of the crop area should be constantly 69 pixels. Can I achieve that with ImageMagick as well? Would it be correct to pass geometry like `9999x9999+0+69` for the `crop`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of operation could be simply performed with [Imagemacick](http://www.imagemagick.org) using [crop](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/) function.

In your example:

```
convert your_image.png -crop 423x275+0+113 -background transparent -flatten cropped_image.png
```

The output is:

[image: Cropped image]

Using a batch file you can process all your images.

**Edit**

*convert* works even using in the geometry dimensions greater than the dimensions of the image itself:

```
convert your_image.png  -crop 9999x9999+0+69 -background transparent -flatten cropped_image.png
```

[image: other cropped image]

Fore more complex operations you can get the attributes of the image using the [identify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) command in your batch file.

As evidenced by @Scribblemacher, you can use [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) in order to simplify the batch operation. Be aware that mogrify overwrites original files.

Comment: I agree--Imagemagick is the tool for this job. You can also also use [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) instead of convert. Mogrify works similar to convert, but can accept a wildcard (e.g. *.png in a directory) and overwrite the original files.

Comment: Please see the updated question.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: That would mean I need to parse output of `identify`, modify it corresponding to my needs and pass it to `mogrify`/`convert`, right?

Comment: No, you can simply use *9999x9999+0+69* as geometry for crop, my example should work. Use the parsing only for more complex operations.